# Data-Theme set to page not applied to header and footer with jquerymobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Maybe there is something obvious I cannot see but I think that setting data-theme in the div with data-role=page  was supposed to set it for everything:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" data-theme="b">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>Page content goes here.</p>      
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

But I still get the default theme A

What am I doing wrong? Or is this a bug?
It was working in 1 alpha 4 but not in 1 final.

Comment: works fine on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YLF9b/), what exactly are you expecting to see?

Comment: No, it does not. Theme B has a blue bar, not black bar http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/themes.html

Comment: it does if you add data-theme="b" to the header itself (as mentioned in the JQM docs you linked) - do you actually mean the cascading styles are not working??

Comment: I mean that setting the theme in the data-role="page" should cascade to the header. In versions before beta2 was working like that. Maybe a regression bug?

Comment: you are right, there actually is a [ticket about this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2655) which is still open...

Comment: cool... at least I'm not stupid :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the docs, http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/pages-themes.html
it specifically says: "However, headers and footers will default to theme "a". If you want to have a page with, for example, only theme "b" for all its elements, including its header and footer, you will need to specify data-theme="b" to the page div as well as the header and footer divs. "

So this is not a bug.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that it's currently a bug and there's a [ticket open about this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2655)

Just moved this from the comments for the OP to be able to mark as answer!

Thanks